# How to connect to sqlite database running in virtual machine on ubuntu

Tags: java, sqlite, ubuntu-12.04, virtual-machine

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            // register the driver 
            String sDriverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = null;
            conn =     DriverManager.getConnection("10.51.0.235///home/shashank/Downloads/org.sqlite.JDBC");
        }
```

Here "10.51.0.235" is the ip address of the of the vm which is running on Ubuntu and the databse which I'm using is SQLite .

Comment: SQLite isn't a server.

Comment: Change the network settings into bridge adapter and check ip again and then share "Downloads" folder to network using samba. Then try the code. Hope it will work(not tested).

Comment: Ya I tried and changed it to bridgr adapter but its not working actually I've been getting "class not found exception" from this line "Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");".
Do I need to have the jdbc driver in my system also because I'm having this jdbc driver in the virtual machine ?